# How to call mutiple id using `this` in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

here I'm doing contact forms.In the same page, I have 10 forms and I want to validate all form.I want to use same validation code for all forms.here I gave id's but the problem is the same id's not working on the same page.I want to use current id.Can anyone suggest how should I do?
Feel free to tell is there any mistakes in my code.
Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
/* name*/ 
 $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var is_name=input.val();
  if(is_name){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });
  
 /* E-mail */ 
 $('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var regex = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
  var is_email=regex.test(input.val());
  if(is_email){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });
  
  /* select People*/
 $('#contact_select').change(function() {
  var select=$(this);
  var selectOption =  $("#contact_select option:selected").val();
  if(selectOption){
   select.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   select.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* select Time*/
 $('#contact_time').change(function() {
  var select=$(this);
  var selectTime =  $("#contact_time option:selected").val();
  if(selectTime){
   select.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   select.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

  
    /* Submit */
 $("#contact_submit button").click(function(event){

  var form_data = $("#contact").serializeArray();

   var error_free = true;
  for (var input in form_data){
   var element = $("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
   var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
   var error_element = $("span", element.parent());

   if (!valid){
    error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show"); 
    error_free=false;
   }
   else{
    error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
   }
  }

  
   if (!error_free){
  return false;
  }
  else {  
   $('.success_msg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
   $('input , textarea , select').val('').removeClass('valid');
   event.preventDefault(); 
  }

 });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row current" id="demo1">
  <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name" required autocomplete="off" />
      <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
      <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div><!--detail-->
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="email" required autocomplete="off" />
      <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
      <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
    </div><!--detail-->
     <div class="btn-container" id="contact_submit">
     <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn"> Submit</button></a>
   </div> 
  </form>
</div>

<div class="row current" id="demo2">
  <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name" required autocomplete="off" />
      <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
      <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div><!--detail-->
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="email" required autocomplete="off" />
      <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
      <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
    </div><!--detail-->
     <div class="btn-container" id="contact_submit">
     <a href="#"><button type="submit" class="btn"> Submit</button></a>
   </div> 
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: ID must be unique, You have to use class.

Comment: @Smit Raval yeah, id must be unique but in jquery, I want to write code only once.how I should write.

Comment: Are you sure about in input as the first argument to the on function, i think it should be event name. $('#contact_name').on('click', function()

Comment: See this https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQY6LS5C80UM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom attribute like `data-validation="validation-type"` on your `input` controls then do a for each on your form with

```
$('<myform>').find('*[data-validation]').each(function(){
 // in here get the this object for each input control the code to validate comes here
 var valType = $(this).attr('data-validation');
  switch(valType)
  {
    case 1:
     //validation of case 1
     break;
     //add other cases as of your need.
  }     

});
```

**Edit 1**

For example you can play around with this snippet:

```js
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  //validating controls for form 1
  debugger;
  $('#myform1').find('*[data-validation]').each(function(e) {
    validateInput(this);
  });
  //validating controls for form 2
  $('#myform2').find('*[data-validation]').each(function(e) {
    validateInput(this);
  });
})

function validateInput(control) {
  if (control == null || control === undefined)
    return null;

  var validType = $(control).attr('data-validation');
  if (validType == null || validType === undefined)
    return null;

  switch (validType) {
    case "text":
      if ($(control).val().trim().length == 0)
        $(control).addClass('invalid').removeClass('valid');
      else
        $(control).addClass('valid').removeClass('invalid');
      break;
    case "number":
      debugger;
      var value = $(control).val().trim();
      if (isNaN(value) || value.length == 0)
        $(control).addClass('invalid').removeClass('valid');
      else
        $(control).addClass('valid').removeClass('invalid');
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>
  Form 1
</h4>
<form id="myform1">
  <label>Enter name</label>
  <input type="text" data-validation="text" value="">
  <br/>
  <label>Enter Age</label>
  <input type="text" data-validation="number" value="">
  <br/>
</form>
<h4>
  Form 2
</h4>
<form id="myform2">
  <label>Enter name</label>
  <input type="text" data-validation="text" value="">
  <br/>
  <label>Enter Age</label>
  <input type="text" data-validation="number" value="">
  <br/>
</form>
<button>
Click me to validate
</button>
```

Comment: According to my code where i have to add.In submit also we have the same id

Comment: Yes, you can add it to your submit but it would be better if you create a function for it and then pass your controller to it.

Comment: @Husna what is the error that you are getting can you post it in here.

Comment: Are you sure about in input as the first argument to the on function, i think it should be event name. $('#contact_name').on('click', function()

Comment: @vikscool you are using validate.js here? I don't want to use any library files.

Comment: @Husna no other library is being used in the above snippet apart from the `JQuery` library.

Comment: @Husna can you explain what it is not able to do? and it would be better if you can update your code. So, we can see that and provide a proper solution.

Comment: @vikscool see in submit we are directly calling `#contact_submit` this is also dynamic and in the switch, you are using simple conditions i have to add complete validation.

Comment: @Husna are you going to post the data from one  at a time or all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170346/discussion-between-vikscool-and-husna).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using HTML5, then adding custom methods for validation is not a good idea.

Try using jquery validation and pattern attribute like:

```
        function submitForm(id){
    var isValid = $("#" + id).valid();
     if(isvalid)
    /* Yes valid*/
   else
    /* Invalid*/
      });
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="row current" id="demo1">
  <form id="contact1" method="post" action="">
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name" required autocomplete="off" />
      <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
      <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div><!--detail-->
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="email" required pattern="^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$" autocomplete="off" />
      <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
      <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
    </div><!--detail-->
        <div class="btn-container" id="contact_submit">
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn" onclick="submitForm('contact1')"> Submit</button></a>
            </div>  
  </form>
</div>

<div class="row current" id="demo2">
  <form id="contact2" method="post" action="">
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name" required autocomplete="off" />
      <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
      <span class="error">This field is required</span>
    </div><!--detail-->
    <div class="detail">
      <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="email" required autocomplete="off" pattern="^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$"/>
      <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
      <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
      <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
    </div><!--detail-->
        <div class="btn-container" id="contact_submit">
                    <a href="#"><button type="button" onclick="submitForm('contact2')" class="btn"> Submit</button></a>
            </div>  
  </form>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Dynamic function called on button clicked. Type is button instead of submit

Hope you will get the point and it helps.

Happy Coding !!!!

Comment: here you directly valid #contact1 what about other forms but I want the same code for all forms.

Comment: Make it dynamic and pass the form name in the function, in HTML onclick event of button. I have updated the code

Comment: how i tried but not getting only default html5 validations working ?

Comment: have you included validation js?

Comment: @ Deep Shah no I don't wan to add other library files.

Comment: its not other third party, its jquery validations. It is the best way I think when there are 10 forms, you dont want to write validation code for each control

Comment: upvoting for your effort.